# Video widget in Pyqt5 and designer

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qt-designer

I'm looking to develop a desktop application with pyqt5 and designer, I want to put a video on the 1st tabwidget but I can't find a dedicated widget for videos on designer I would like to have a solution thank you

Comment: Welcome. What have you tried yourself so far? It's not clear what you need. Have you any git repository to go to? Right now your question is too broad. Have you made any research on your own? Maybe you'd like to show examples of what information you used.

Comment: How to add video in UI created using Qt Designer with a promoted widget which is a QVideoWidget?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49423350/how-to-add-video-in-ui-created-using-qt-designer-with-a-promoted-widget-which-is/49423852#49423852